# Check if node is empty and if empty set to value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Below is my code. Basically, what the problem is is that I need to be able to check a node, if it's blank, set it to 0, but if it has a value, set it to that value. Then afterwards I need to do math on it (subtract values). Below is what I tried, but I am getting an error "The variable parameter 'quantAvail' is either not defined or it is out of scope." I'm not sure how to resolve that?

```
<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="quantitybackordered=''">
                    <xsl:variable name="quantBackOrdered" select="0"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="quantBackOrdered" select="quantitybackordered"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="locationquantityavailable=''">
                    <xsl:variable name="quantAvail" select="0"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="quantAvail" select="locationquantityavailable"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="inventoryLocation_internalid='18'">
                    <xsl:variable name="quantTotal" select="$quantAvail - $quantBackOrdered"/> <!-- Error on this line -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$quantTotal"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="test" select="locationquantityavailable"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$test=''">
                            <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="locationquantityavailable"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to advise without seeing the context (both the input and the rest of the stylesheet), but I believe you could rewrite the part in your question as:

```
<xsl:variable name="quantBackOrdered">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="quantitybackordered=''">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="quantitybackordered" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="quantAvail">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="locationquantityavailable=''">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="locationquantityavailable" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="inventoryLocation_internalid='18'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quantAvail - $quantBackOrdered"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quantAvail"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```